# Reading/Writing None values as null with ReactiveMongo

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, spray-json

We are in the process of migrating an existing REST service from Spring/Java to Spray using ReactiveMongo.  One of the requirements for the migration (the first phase of it anyway), is that all inputs and outputs must match the current system.  The issue with this is the business objects allow `null` values - both at rest in the datastore, and when returned in GET methods on the service.  Fields can be missing as input to the service for PUT/POST, but the corresponding values must still be written as `null` to the datastore and returned the same.

Normally 'not required' fields aren't an issue for Scala/Spray through the use of `Option`, but the issue I'm having is actually **writing** the values of the `Option` fields as `null` when persisting, and setting the fields as `None` when **reading** the same `null` from Mongo.

In the research I've been doing, I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Here are snippets of my code:

**UserPersistent**

```
case class UserPersistent(id: Option[String], name: Option[String])
```

**PersistentUser**

```
object PersistentUser {

    implicit object PersistentUserReader extends BSONDocumentReader[UserPersistent] {
        def read(doc: BSONDocument): UserPersistent = UserPersistent(
            id = doc.getAs[String]("_id"),
            name = doc.getAs[String]("name")
        )
    }

    implicit object PersistentUserWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[UserPersistent] {
        override def write(persisted: UserPersistent): BSONDocument = {
            BSONDocument(
                "_id" -> persisted.id,
                "name" -> persisted.name
            )
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried the following on the `write()` side, and although the code compiles and runs, it throws a `NullPointerException` when executed

```
"name" -> {
    val nnn = persisted.name match {
        case Some(n) => n
        case _       => null
    }
    nnn
}
```

I have used `OptionFormat` for the 'presentation' of the data, which returns `null`s (but for everything), but I need to take care of the Mongo side of this.

Surely there's a way to do this - what am I missing?

Comment: `Option[T]` can be directly read or written, as long as there is reader and/or writer for `T`. Just `"name" -> persisted.name` (see [doc](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/bson/typeclasses.html))

Comment: Using `reactivemongo.bson.BSONNull` instead of `null` may get rid of the NPE in your code up there.

As a generally more long term solution, if the default `Option[T]` bson format (writer and reader) don't behave the way you want them to, maybe you can define your own `Option[T]` writer/reader/format that uses `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
object PersistentUser {
    implicit val reader: BSONDocumentReader[UserPersistent] = Macros.reader[UserPersistent]
    implicit val writer: BSONDocumentWriter[UserPersistent] = Macros.writer[UserPersistent]
    }
```